# Linking to a specific item on a jQuery portfolio-style gallery (Galleriffic)

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, galleriffic

I created a demo for you, [here](http://lorenzoraffio.com/test.php) it is. As you can see there is a main image with a related caption and other small images below. If you click one of them the main image/caption changes to display the one you selected.
If you notice when you hover the pointer on any of the images below the big one you get a link like test.php/#image3 or test.php/#image6.

I'm looking for a way to have that if you visit test.php/#image3 (directly, not through the onClick event) you have the #image3 as main image (so without having to click on it). The same for test.php/#image4 / #image5, etc.

Comment: you need to create the gallery using php and then add your jquery

Comment: There isn't a way to retrieve the #imageX from the URL and load it like it was an onClick event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$url  =  window.location.hash;
```

this gives you the #imagex part of the url

Comment: How can I make sure it's loaded onLoad (so that the image/caption change according to the hash)?

Comment: What ever code you use for the click event, paste that just with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` - modify it so that the value is the above $url variable rather than what ever it is now. Unfortunately I can't be more specific as I can't find you click even in your example